# Adding new column to an existing dataframe column base on a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe  with the below column names, and I want to create a new column based on a given condition. The condition are to create a new column **Race** for each unique **EVENT_ID** in the dataframe check for rows in the **WIN_LOSE** that has 1 as value, take the **SELECTION_TRAP** value that corespond to that **WIN_LOSE** row and create the **Race**.

I tried using the pandas where function but I an not getting it right

```
df['Race'] = df.where(df['WIN_LOSE']==1,df['SELECTION_TRAP'],axis = 0)

EVENT_ID    SELECTION_TRAP  WIN_LOSE
174331755       1             0
174331755       2             0
174331755       7             1
174331755       4             0
174331755       3             0
174331755       6             0
174331755       8             0
174329130       5             0
174329130       7             1
174329130       1             0
174329130       4             0
174329130       2             0
174329130       8             0
```

My expected  output should look this.

```
EVENT_ID    SELECTION_TRAP  WIN_LOSE  RACE
174331755       7             1        7
174329130       7             1        7
```

Comment: Whats happen if no `1` per group?

Comment: Whats happens if multiple `1` per group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by `1` in `WIN_LOSE` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then assign new column.

```
df1 = df[df['WIN_LOSE']==1].copy()
df1['RACE'] = df1['SELECTION_TRAP']
print (df1)
    EVENT_ID  SELECTION_TRAP  WIN_LOSE  RACE
2  174331755               7         1     7
8  174329130               7         1     7
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can create your column called 'RACE', when 'WIN_LOSE' equals 1, and then filter your df:

```
df.loc[df['WIN_LOSE'].eq(1),'RACE'] = df['SELECTION_TRAP']
df.loc[df.RACE.notnull()]
```

Prints back:

```
    EVENT_ID  SELECTION_TRAP  WIN_LOSE  RACE
2  174331755               7         1   7.0
8  174329130               7         1   7.0
```